# Hide fields based on user role

Tags: php, css, wordpress

How can I hide fields using CSS for specific users?
Something like this:

```
if( $role == 'subscriber' ) {    ?>
<style type="text/css">
    .user-area .user-profile-dropdown{
        display: none !important;
    }
</style>
```

I used this code and it did not work:

```
function hide_fields_nonusers(){
if( $role == 'subscriber' ) {    ?>
<style type="text/css">
    .user-area .user-profile-dropdown{
        display: none !important;
    }
</style>
}
add_action('admin_head', 'hide_fields_nonusers');
```

Comment: First: How did it not work? Second: Are you trying to hide the data only on the client-side?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't do anything!

Comment: Will it become a problem if someone uses the developer console on their browser to read the hidden data?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing closing the HTML output:

```
function hide_fields_nonusers(){
if( $role == 'subscriber' ) {    ?>
<style type="text/css">
  .user-area .user-profile-dropdown{
     display: none !important;
 }
</style>
<?php }
```

Comment: What do you mean? The code you entered its identical with my code. What would be the correct code?

Comment: I fixed the syntax error and tested it, it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
if( current_user_can('subscriber')) {   
?>
<style type="text/css">
.user-area .user-profile-dropdown{
 display: none !important;
 }
</style>
<?php 

}
```